# ExactTarget A/B Testing page is blank

Tags: marketing-cloud, error, chrome

When I try to load the A/B testing page of the Email app, it fails to load the javascript source `page-overview.js`.  This is using Chromium Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 12.04 (260972).

What is strange is on another account I have access to, the page loads correctly with the same browser/etc.

The error is

```
GET https://app.s1.exct.net/abtesting2/js/page-overview.js net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS 


> GET https://app.s1.exct.net/abtesting2/js/page-overview.js
> net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS require.min.js:6 req.addScriptToDom
> require.min.js:6 req.attach require.min.js:6 req.load require.min.js:6
> c require.min.js:6 b.require require.min.js:6 b.configure
> require.min.js:6 requirejs require.min.js:6 (anonymous function)
> require.min.js:6 (anonymous function) require.min.js:6 Uncaught Error:
> Load timeout for modules: page-overview 
> http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout require.min.js:6
> makeError require.min.js:6 J require.min.js:6 (anonymous function)
```

[image]

Comment: You should submit a case to help@exacttarget.com or call using the numbers here: http://www.exacttarget.com/services/technical-support 
This is likely an account specific issue that needs internal troubleshooting.